# How to Upload Multiple Images from Multiple Browsing in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, input, image-uploading

This is my first question in Stack Overflow. Any suggestions woule be really appreciated.

I'm working on creating a website and the main function of it is to allow user to upload images as many as they want. It can come from different folders and users are able to browse for images as many times as they want. In addition, users can preview image they selected. In case users do not want one of photos selected at first. User can delete it by clicking the button near by the previewed image.

At View Part of Laravel, you will see the button to browse multiple files with the text to tell users how many photos selected right now. When I'm working with View Part, it seems to work perfectly. However, the result after store the form. It shows that it stored only the photos selected come from the last time browsing only.

To see more clear picture, here is the example.

- User choose 4 photos which are A, B, C, and D
- Those 4 photos are previewed and each of them have the deleted button next to it
- User do not want D, so user delete it by clicking the button near the preview section
- The left photos are A, B, and C
- User want to upload more photos
- User choose 3 more photos which are E, F, and G
- The total number of photo to preview is 6 (A, B, C, E, F, G)
- A, B, and C are from the first time browsing
- E, F, and G are from the second time browsing
- User do not want G, so user delete it by clicking the button near the preview section
- The left photos are A, B, C, E, and F
- Finally, user click submit button

The expected and correct result of storing this from is to have A, B, C, E, and F as the photos selected from user. However, it turn out that the database only store E and F which are the photos from the second time browsing.

I want to fix it so it can save the correct photos; in this case, A, B, C, E, and F.

I use javascript to add or remove the preview image and add the checkbox to store the name of the image selected. I will use this later in the Controller to check whether it is the file user want to store or not. Here is the code :

```
var totalFiles = [];

    function handleFileSelect(evt) {

        // FileList object
        var files = evt.target.files; 

        // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

            // Only process image files.
            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                continue;
            }

            var reader = new FileReader();

            // Closure to capture the file information.
            reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                return function(e) {
                // Render thumbnail.
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.innerHTML = ['<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="' , theFile.name, '" style="display: none;" checked /><img width=50% height="auto" class="thumb p-3" src="', e.target.result,
                                    '" title="', theFile.name, '"/>', "<button onclick='deleteImage()'>" + "<i class='fas fa-trash-alt' aria-hidden='true'></i>" + " ลบรูปภาพ</button><br/>"].join('');

                document.getElementById('preview_photo').insertBefore(span, null);
                };
            })(f);

            totalFiles.push(f);

            // Read in the image file as a data URL.
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }

        if(Array.from(totalFiles).length > 0){
            document.getElementById('count_selected_photo').innerHTML = "Image Selected:  " + Array.from(totalFiles).length + " Photo(s)";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('count_selected_photo').innerHTML = "No Image Selected";
        }
    }


    function deleteImage() { 
        var index = Array.from(document.getElementById('preview_photo').children).indexOf(event.target.parentNode)
        document.querySelector("#preview_photo").removeChild( document.querySelectorAll('#preview_photo span')[index]);

        totalFiles.splice(index, 1); 

        if(Array.from(totalFiles).length > 0){
            document.getElementById('count_selected_photo').innerHTML = "Image Selected:  " + Array.from(totalFiles).length + " Photo(s)";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('count_selected_photo').innerHTML = "No Image Selected";
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('before_photo').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

In Controller, I use `request->file('before_photo')` to get the file selected before deleting and get the name of photo selected by using `request->input('selected')` and compare these two together. If the name of the file in `request->file('before_photo')` is the same in `request->input('selected')`, it will store this photo. If not, which means user delete it before clicking submit, it will not store.

Here is some part of my code in Controller :

```
// Store Photo If Existed
                    if (request()->hasFile('before_photo')) {
                        // File Chosen at First Time
                        $before_photos = $request->file('before_photo');

                        // File Chosen After Delete Image
                        $selected_photos = $request->input('selected');

                        // Collect Path of Each Photo
                        $paths  = [];

                        // Collect File Name of Each Photo
                        $filenames = [];

                        foreach($selected_photos as $selected_photo){
                            foreach ($before_photos as $before_photo) {
                                // If File Name of Chosen Photo at First Time = File Name of Photo After Deleting
                                if($before_photo->getClientOriginalName() == $selected_photo){

                                    // Transform The File Name to be 'before-photo-TIME-name-originalFileName'
                                    $filename = "before-photo-" . time() . "-name-" . $before_photo->getClientOriginalName();
                                    $paths[] = $before_photo->storeAs('', $filename, 'irepair_photo');
                                    array_push($filenames, $filename);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Transform List of Photo Name into Array
                        $repair_ticket->before_photo = $filenames;
                    }
```

If you have any suggestion or comments on this, please leave your message below. 
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Here is repo https://github.com/Guley/Laravel-Media-Manager

Comment: @PHP Ninja Thank you for your suggestions. Could you please tell me more about this? How can I adapt the media management to my code after finish 'composer update'?

Comment: Would you be interested in an implementation using Vue.js?

Comment: @tamrat Anything would be OK if it can be used in laravel. Could you give me some guideline?

Comment: @tamrat I don't have any background knowledge about Vue.js. Is it easier to do it with Vue.js instead of javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be what you are looking for but should guide you in the right direction. I see you are using vanilla JavaScript which might make things trickier. But since you are also using Laravel and Laravel ships with Vue support (at least it used to), I'll be showing you my implementation using Vue. If you know JavaScript, it shouldn't be that hard to understand as Vue is very easy.

The trick with multi file uploading is to use another array to store your files as the native `FileList` object that is returned by the file input is immutable. Look at the code snippets below (I have tried to add comments to explain what I'm doing.)

You can see a working example in this [pen](https://codepen.io/takdw/pen/JjdNpPK).

```html
<!-- @change is the Vue equivalent of onchange -->
<input @change="handleFileSelect" type="file" multiple>
<ul>
  <li v-for="(photo, index) in photos" :key="`thumb-${index}`">
    <img :src="photo.preview" :alt="photo.file.name">
    <button @click="removePhoto(index)" type="button">Remove Photo</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the HTML section, all we have to do is to listen to changes to the file input and setup a place where we can display thumbnails for the selected images. Vue makes this very easy by using the `v-for` directive to iterate over an array. The current element in the iteration is available for the `li` and its child elements and we can use it to populate attributes such as the `img`'s `src`.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      photos: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleFileSelect(e) {
      Array.from(e.target.files).forEach(file => {
        // perform check here such as making sure its an image

        const reader = new FileReader()
        
        reader.onload = () => {
          // push the preview result and also the file to photos array
          this.photos.push({
            preview: reader.result,
            file
          })
        }
        
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
      })
    },
    removePhoto(index) {
      this.photos.splice(index, 1)
    },
    upload() {
      const fd = new FormData()

      this.photos.forEach((photo, index) => {
        // we only want to append the actual file, excluding the preview
        // so we only append the `file` attribute
        fd.append(`photo-${index}`, photo.file)
      })

      // send the data
      // for example, using axios
      const uploadEndpoint = ''
      axios.post(uploadEndpoint, fd, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' // important
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

The JavaScript part is pretty easy. What we are doing here is setting up a `photos` "local state" to store our photos. We use this variable to iterate over and display thumbnails in our HTML. When a user selects images, we take the files and generate a thumbnail for them using the `FileReader` object and push it to the `photos` variable along with the actual file.

```js
{
  preview: 'data:image/....', // the file preview generated by the FileReader
  file: File object // the actual file the user selected
}
```

When a user wants to unselect an image, we just `splice` it from the `photos` array so the `photos` array will always contain photos the user wants to upload. When we come to uploading, if we are using AJAX to send the request we can just create a `FormData` object and append each photo to it by iterating over the `photos` variable. In a Laravel backend, these photos can then be accessed using `request()->file()`. Before sending your request you have to set the proper headers though, mainly the `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`.

I hope this gave you some general idea on how to proceed with this issue. If you have any questions feel free to leave them in the comments section and I'll try my best to explain more.

---

**UPDATE**: More info on working with the photos on your Laravel Backend

Once you are successfully sending the request from your front end, you can access the photos/files using Laravel's `request()->file()` helper function. This will return all the files in the request in an array.

```php
dd(request()->file());
```

Output will look something like:

```
array:3 [
  "photo-0" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#221
    -test: false
    -originalName: "The Dark Reef Fugitive.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpjr6Cx5"
    basename: "phpjr6Cx5"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpjr6Cx5"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpjr6Cx5"
    aTime: 2020-03-03 08:29:19
    mTime: 2020-03-03 08:29:19
    cTime: 2020-03-03 08:29:19
    inode: 12976169
    size: 298634
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo-1" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#243
    -test: false
    -originalName: "Nevermore.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "php3LNGW5"
    basename: "php3LNGW5"
    pathname: "/tmp/php3LNGW5"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/php3LNGW5"
    aTime: 2020-03-03 08:29:19
    mTime: 2020-03-03 08:29:19
    cTime: 2020-03-03 08:29:19
    inode: 12976170
    size: 322173
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo-2" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#250
    -test: false
    -originalName: "Magnanumus.png"
    -mimeType: "image/png"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpJZ9El6"
    basename: "phpJZ9El6"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpJZ9El6"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpJZ9El6"
    aTime: 2020-03-03 08:29:19
    mTime: 2020-03-03 08:29:19
    cTime: 2020-03-03 08:29:19
    inode: 12976172
    size: 1068594
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
]
```

As you can see each file is an instance of `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`. To store this file, you have a couple of options. One is to use the `store` or `storeAs` function on the file or just use the `Storage` facade's `put` or `putFileAs` method. Here is an example:

```php
$filePaths = collect(request()->file())->values()->map(function ($photo) {
  return Storage::put('photos', $photo);
  // OR
  // return Storage::putFileAs('photos', $photo, $photo->getClientOriginalName());
  // OR
  // return $photo->store('photos');
  // OR
  // return $photo->storeAs('photos', $photo->getClientOriginalName());
});
```

Read the [Laravel docuemntation on file storage](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#storing-files) to understand other options.

`$filePaths` will be an array of paths where the photos were stored.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm really appreciated that. I will try to adapt what you said and I will get you feedback if it's working or not. I may have some questions to ask further. It would be really grateful if you could help me to succeed this thing. Thank you again.

Comment: Play around with pen I provided to understand it a bit more.

Comment: I'm just working with it and it turn THIS ERROR >> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Use of undefined constant photos - assumed 'photos' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: D:\XAMPP\htdocs\ioffice\resources\views\iRepair\request_forms\fill_form.blade.php) Do I have to define 'photos' somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. I'll provide you a gist with a full implementation (how you can integrate it an actual Laravel project) in a bit.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/takdw/ab9792a19f9ff324d3c02e030b737b87

Comment: Thank you for your time and efford. You're so kind to me. I will try to fix my code again and get you feedback as soon as possible.

Comment: I created MultiUploader.vue in "components" folder under "resources/js" and I found a problem which is Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'vue'. Do I have to install any specific packages for vue? Another problem is that <li class="w-1/4 group" v-for="(photo, index) in photos"> cannot be used. It showed that "[vue/require-v-for-key] Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives." Do I have to change v-for?

Comment: Yes. You do need to install Vue using NPM (`npm install vue` or `yarn add vue`). To fix the `v-for` issue update the code to `<li v-for="(photo, index) in photos" :key="\`thumb-${index}\`">`. The CSS classes are there because I'm using Tailwind CSS. You can also pull that in from CDN or via NPM.

Comment: I already install vue and fix the version conflict. However, I can't adapt it with the form in the view myself. It seems something wrong because of "[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app" keep showing up. How can I adapt the 'multi-uploader' with the form in the view and get the value of 'photos' in the controller? Could you help me figure it out?

Comment: It's telling you the exact error. Vue needs to be attached to a single DOM element you specify. In our case, we are attaching Vue to an element with an ID of `app`. If you look at the `app.blade.php` file in the Gist I attached, there is a `div` with an ID of `app` right next to the `body` tag. Add that element to your code and it should be working. Read through the code in Gist very carefully and also read up a bit on Vue (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/).

Comment: I already attach the div contains id="app" in the form.blade.php but it keep telling me that it cannot find this element. Do I have to adapt my form into Vue Template and define the route for "/upload"?

Comment: Ok, I am not sure what is causing this but if you really have an `#app` element and your Vue instance isn't finding it, check how you're importing your JavaScript assets. Make sure the script is run after the page finishes loading. If your `script` tag is at the top of the page, add a `defer` attribute to it. Or just have it at the bottom of the page before the body closing tag.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already fix 'Cannot find this element' problem. I think the reason why it returned error like that is because I defined app.js twice. This time, I used 'defer' as you suggested and that's working fine. Thank you again. I'm working throught your code right now. I will try to test whether 'photos' can be accessed or not and give you feedback as soon as I can.

Comment: When I click the upload button. The 'response' is printed at the console with status '200' and statusText 'OK' which I think that the upload is working fine? At this time, I want to fix my controller to be able to access the value of 'photos' and store it to the database. Could you give me some guildeline to do it?

Comment: I have edited my answer with more information. Take a look at it.

Comment: I already use 'dd(request()->file());' in my controller to test whether it can access the data in 'photos' or not, but I can't see anything except the log of 'response' in the console. Plus, the current page seems to unable to pass this 'photos' variable to the controller. After clicking the upload button, I can't go to other page. I have set route something like this : Route::post('upload','iRepair\RequestFormsController@store'); but it seems it cannot go to this function in the controller. Can't figure it out why?

Comment: To see the output of the `dd` go to the network tab and see the response of the network call.

Comment: I can't dd to dump the content of 'photos' out. However, I can see the content in the Network Tab. When I click the Upload button, it cannot go to other page. Do I have to set the specific route for this? Do I miss something on my code? In addition, how can I adapt this multi-uploader with form? I need to send variable like 'request_subject' and 'request_details' with 'photos'. How can I do it? Please help me more.

Comment: Here is the contents of the response for `dd(request()->file())` - [https://i.imgur.com/CJs14B8.png] You have to setup a route that listens for your upload request. And you can add additional fields to your form by using `fd.append()`.

Comment: Thank you for time and effort. I'm really appreciated that. Now, I can adapt the form and store data to the database already. However; after click upload button, I can't redirect to the page I want. Do I have to define the specific routes in web.php?

Comment: Since you sent the request via `axios`, your response is going to be handled by `axios`. You can redirect to your desired page on the front end in the `then` block of your `axios` request. `axios.post(...).then(() => { ...; window.location = 'path-here'; }`

Comment: Thank you so much. You gave such a great advice. Thank you for taking your time on teaching me how to do it with Vue.js. Now, I can finish this function. However, there're a lot more to do in my project. I wish to learn a lot more from you. Hope you doing great on your work as well.